# Smart Contract's ABI has uint256, but I get error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'BigNumber'

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

This is the first time I work with web3 api, so I am totally lost. I use wagmi hook with react, trying to call a function from smart contract:

```
const id = 1;
const index = 1;

 const { data, error, isError, isLoading } = useContractRead({
    address: "THE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS",
    abi: [(...){
        inputs: [
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "id", type: "uint256" },
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "index", type: "uint256" },
        ],
        name: "isClaimed",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
      },(...)],
    functionName: "isClaimed",
    args: [id, index],
  });
```

and I get the IDE error: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'BigNumber'"

if I then

```
 const id = BigNumber.from(1);
```

then I get error from the contract:

> Error: call revert exception [ See:
> https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]
> (method="isClaimed(uint256,uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null,
> errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION,
> version=abi/5.7.0)
> at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
> at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
> at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
> at index.ts:400:1
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

I watched several tutorials and read articles about it but still have no idea what is the problem. Wagmi documentation doesn't tell me anything about it. Can anyone help?

------------ Edit: Additional Info ----------------

I have this in my App.txs:

```
const chains = [arbitrum, mainnet, polygon];
const projectId = "SOME_ID_OF_WALLETCONNECT_PROJECT_I_CREATED";

const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiClient = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 1, chains }),
  provider,
});
```

Contract developer said that chain is Mumbai testing for polygon. I guess I am not connected to the correct chain then

Comment: You're not passing the correct address, `address: "0xADDRESS"` unless thats intention obfuscation

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should be more specific there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Contract Dev pointed out that I should be using polygonMumbai chain with wagmi.
So I added

```
import { arbitrum, mainnet, polygon, polygonMumbai } from "wagmi/chains";

const chains = [arbitrum, mainnet, polygon, polygonMumbai];
```

and it works.